# How do I talk to a machine with the same IP as me but on a different subnet?

Tags: networking, subnet, ipv4

Suppose I am on one subnet and I want to send a message to another machine on a sibling subnet that has the same IP address as me.

What is the syntax, conceptually and practically, to get my message there? What are the steps involved?

I've created a simple diagram to emphasize

[image: same ip different subnets]

Comment: You don't talk directly. You can only talk via a third party.

Comment: @MichaelHampton what do you mean by "directly"? Meaning I don't address my message to "192.168.1.2" ? Ok.. but who do I address my message to?

Comment: You write a whole new protocol, under which you run a server out on the Internet somewhere. Both you and your correspondent must independently connect to that server. It can then relay messages for you. Or you use an existing protocol which works this way. Or better yet, you just use IPv6, which solves this problem and a lot more. This happens to be a good illustration of why, for instance, gaming protocols like Xbox One _only_ run on IPv6.

Comment: How does IPv6 solve this problem? My question would then be what to do if two machines on different subnets have the same ipv6 address

Comment: Two machines on different subnets will never have the same IPv6 address. You can simply connect directly (if firewalls permit).

Comment: For the way your diagram is drawn the routers would need to forward specific ports to specific internal addresses, then userA connects to the IP on the WAN side of userB's router.

Answer (score 2):

Routers at the edge of both networks will have to do a one-to-one NAT.

In other words, the IP address of each machine will need to be translated to a different IP address that is compatible to send across the network.

There is no way to communicate with another machine on a different network that has the same IP without NAT.

Comment: So each time I want to talk to someone with the same IP as me on a different subnet, I need to ask the IT guy to set up a NAT?

Comment: @CodyBugstein No each time it happens you ask for IPv6, and if you get a no you ask for a NAT configuration for that one machine.

Comment: @kasperd Ask who? The local IT guy?

Comment: @CodyBugstein You ask the same person you'd ask if the network connection was down.

Comment: @CodyBugstein no. This is typically a situation that occurs when two companies merge together or establish a VPN together. In that case there is typically an intermediary subnet created that each conflicting subnet is translated in to. It is not done on a machine by machine basis, unless you want to do that. Usually the goal is to allow the entire network to talk to each other. You didn’t provide any use case, so I don’t k ow who you ask. I would assume if you find yourself in this situation that you have an idea of who to ask.